# OutofMemory Exception (when cropping an Image)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to crop an Image that coming from a byte array. Unlucky, I get the OutofMemory Exception in my cropImage function. this part show how I write it on a file.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(strArr);

System.Drawing.Rectangle oRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle();
oRectangle.X = 50;
oRectangle.Y = 100;
oRectangle.Height = 180;
oRectangle.Width = 240;

System.Drawing.Image oImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
cropImage(oImage, oRectangle);
name = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg";
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath(name), strArr);
context.Response.Write("http://local.x.com/test/" + name);
```

and this part is my crop Image function which is obvious what it is doing..

```
private static System.Drawing.Image cropImage(System.Drawing.Image img, System.Drawing.Rectangle cropArea)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
    bmpImage.PixelFormat);
    return (System.Drawing.Image)(bmpCrop);
}
```

and this is how I construct my strArr

```
System.IO.Stream str = context.Request.InputStream;
int strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
byte[] strArr = new byte[strLen];
str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);
string st = String.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(strArr, x => x.ToString("X2"))); // try 4
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the cropArea value is. I'm thinking that it may have some very large upper limits, causing the system to try and allocate a gigantic image for the return value of bmpImage.Clone(...). I suggest you debug you application and examine this cropArea variable.

Comment: Please, read my answer. We have faced this problem in production. There is no solution except using another imaging API.

Comment: @SimonEjsing, it is that rectangle (oRectangle) actually I created at the top part of the code

Comment: @RamanZhylich: If that is the case, can you then provide your solution or part of it, instead of just quoting a recommendation from MSDN?

Comment: The solution is to use Windows Imaging Components. Please read my answer attentively.

Comment: Is there a chance that you are feeding erroneous data to Bitmap object so OutOfMemory is caused by error dimension? I wonder how 'strArr' is constructed?

Comment: I can add a little bit more info about it

Comment: @JiajiWu, more details added.

Comment: I suspect it's an encoding problem. You probably need to determine which encoding is used for the `Request.InputStream`. I suggest you try to save the byte array to a local file first (before doing any other operations like `cropImage`), and then try to open it in an image viewer. This way, you can verify if the image from the request stream is in the format/encoding you expect. Base on that, we can do further investigation.

Comment: hey guise, i fixed the error with better solution. check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cropped it from byte array directly and it just works :) thanks everyone who tried their best to help me.

```
public byte[] CropImage(int x, int y, int w, int h, byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            Bitmap bmpCropped = new Bitmap(w, h);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCropped);

            Rectangle rectDestination = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpCropped.Width, bmpCropped.Height);
            Rectangle rectCropArea = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

            g.DrawImage(img, rectDestination, rectCropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.Dispose();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            bmpCropped.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using System.Drawing namespace in ASP.NET is not recommended. 
MSDN:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.

Comment: this function is located in my ashx file. Do you think this is why it is?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. We've experienced it in production application. Please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx at the top. Even if it will work on your box, you won't be sure it will work on other boxes.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) says that `Windows Imaging Components` are a supported alternative to this namespace for ASP applications.

Comment: -1: "This will lead to sporadic OutOfMemory exceptions" It does not say this. You did.

Comment: If it doesn't say that then it doesn't mean I'm not right. BTW I corrected the post

Comment: @RamanZhylich: Well now you are not even answering the question... It works fine, believe me, I have used it a lot without issues. Not supported here means 'no warranty' that it will work. And there is an issue, tough luck, we wont fix it.